# Antlr weird parentheses syntax

Tags: syntax, antlr, grammar, left-recursion

[image]

Cant understand this round bracket meaning.
Its not necessary to write it, but sometimes it can produce left-recursion error. Where should we use it in grammar rules?

Comment: It's called a ["grouping"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form#Table_of_symbols). When you write a sequence of symbols enclosed in parentheses ("round brackets"), the sequence is treated as a single group that occurs before or after other symbols for a rule. For example "S : a (b | c)* d;" can denote the language { ad, abd, acd, abbd, accd, abcd, acbd, etc. }. You can always write an equivalent BNF grammar for an EBNF grammar, and would do so if you have problems with Antlr4 accepting your grammar--which is not often.

Answer (score 0):

> Its not necessary to write it,

That is correct, it is not necessary. Just remove them.

> but sometimes it can produce left-recursion error.

If that really is the case, you can open an issue here: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

### EDIT

Seeing kaby76's comment, just to make sure: you cannot just remove them from a grammar file regardless. They can be removed from your example rule.

When used like this:

```
rule
 : ID '=' ( NUMBER | STRING ) // match either `ID '=' NUMBER` 
                              //           or `ID '=' STRING`
 ;
```

they cannot be removed because removing them wold result in:

```
rule
 : ID '=' NUMBER | STRING // match either `ID '=' NUMBER` 
                          //           or `STRING`
 ;
```

Or with repetition:

```
rule
 : ( ID STRING )+ // match: `ID STRING ID STRING ID STRING ...`
 ;
```

and this:

```
rule
 : ID STRING+ // match: `ID STRING STRING STRING ...`
 ;
```